# Cannot instantiate template with const char * array

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Need help on below code, very confused on what's wrong.

```
template<const char* (&ArrayC)[]>
        class TypeDescriptionBase
        {
        public:
            static const auto getType(int index)
            {
                return getArrayIndex(ArrayC, index);
            }
            template <typename Func>
            static void forEachType(Func&& f)
            {
                for (const auto& type : ArrayC)
                    f(type);
            }
            static auto findTypeIndex(const CString& strType)
            {
                auto it = std::find(std::begin(ArrayC), std::end(ArrayC), strType);
                return static_cast<int>(it == std::end(ArrayC) ? 0 : std::distance(std::begin(ArrayC), it));
            }
        };

        using advancedTypes = TypeDescriptionBase<{ "TypeA", "TpyeB" , "TpyeC", "TpyeD", "TpyeE", "TpyeF", "TpyeG", "TpyeH", "TpyeI", "TpyeJ"}>;
```

I got error - "expected an expression" with the last line around beginning of const char* array. I am using VS2017 for my development.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't C++. [The proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0424r2.pdf) to go down this route was [reviewed positively](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7ca2sh/2017_albuquerque_iso_c_committee_reddit_trip/) at Albuquerque.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use an array of strings as a template parameter.  This is not supported in C++.  Even a single string cannot be a template parameter in C++.  Individual characters can, because they are integral types.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use integral types in templates. Among them, you  have references so you can use reference as template type.

```
template<std::vector<std::string> & temp>
class TypeDescriptionBase
{
public:
    static void ListTypes()
    {
        for (auto const & it: temp)
        {
            std::cout<<it<<std::endl;             
        }
    }    
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> vect;//must not be local as it must have external linkage!

    vect.emplace_back("Type1");
    vect.emplace_back("Type2");
    vect.emplace_back("Type3");
    vect.emplace_back("Type4");

    TypeDescriptionBase<vect> types;
    types.ListTypes();

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Type1                                                                                                                                                       
> Type2                                                                                                                                                       
> Type3                                                                                                                                                       
> Type4
> ```